# Missing conjunction for multiple Organizations in BibLaTex APA style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have this MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Nachfolgend die Referenz \autocite{BundesministeriumfurWirtschaftundEnergie.2019}

\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]    % Literaturverzeichnis in Inhaltsverzeichnis
\end{document}
```

and the following .bib entry created by Citavi:

```
@misc{BundesministeriumfurWirtschaftundEnergie.2019,
 year = {2019-09-18},
 title = {Blockchain-Strategie der Bundesregierung},
 url = {https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/service/publikationen/blockchain-strategie-der-bundesregierung-1672384},
 urldate = {2023-08-25},
 abstract = {},
 organization = {{Bundesministerium f{\"u}r Wirtschaft und Energie} and {Bundesministerium der Finanzen}},
 date = {2019-09-18}
}
```

The output in the bibliography is as follows:

[image]

It's even more noticeable in the font I'm using in my project:

[image]

**Notice the missing conjunction between the two organizations.** I expected the output like this:

> Blockchain-Strategie der Bundesregierung. (2019, 18. September).
> *Bundesministerium für Wirtschaft und Energie **&** Bundesministerium der Finanzen.* Verfügbar 25. August 2023 unter
> https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/service/publikationen/blockchain-strategie-der-bundesregierung-1672384

As far as I can see, the .bib entry should be correct, as it puts each organization in curly brackets and puts an "and" in between.

Can somebody please tell me why there is no conjunction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `apa.bbx` file messes up the list formatting of the `organization` field with `\DeclareListFormat[misc]{organization}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` (it cuts out the loop which inserts the delimiters), you need to redefine the list format:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
 @misc{BundesministeriumfurWirtschaftundEnergie.2019,
 year = {2019-09-18},
 title = {Blockchain-Strategie der Bundesregierung},
 url = {https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/service/publikationen/blockchain-strategie-der-bundesregierung-1672384},
 urldate = {2023-08-25},
 abstract = {},
 organization = {{Test Organisation} and {Bundesministerium f{\"u}r Wirtschaft und Energie} and {Bundesministerium der Finanzen}},
 date = {2019-09-18}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareListFormat[misc]{organization}{%
\mkbibemph{#1%
\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount} + 1}{<}{\value{liststop}}{\multilistdelim}{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{listcount} + 1}{\value{liststop}}{\addspace\&\addspace}{}%
}%
}}

\begin{document}
Nachfolgend die Referenz \autocite{BundesministeriumfurWirtschaftundEnergie.2019}

\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]    % Literaturverzeichnis in Inhaltsverzeichnis
\end{document}
```

Only two organizations:

[image]

More than two organizations:

[image]

**Edit:** I just updated the answer with a code snippet that allows more than two organizations and have the first separated by comma `,`, while the last two (or just two) are separated by a conjuncture sign `&`.

**2nd Edit:** Furthermore, I opened up an issue on the GitHub page of the `apa` style developer. In the [next release](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/218#issuecomment-1697919208) this drawback should be fixed in general.